# Initialize a hash's values by an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

We have a hash and an array:

```
hsh = {name: "", age: "", height: "", weight: ""}
arr  = ["joe", "19", "179", "70"]
```

we want:

```
hsh = {name: "joe", age: "19", height: "179", weight: "70"}
```

my solution which works fine is:

```
hsh.keys.each_with_index {|k,i| hsh[k] = arr[i]}
```

is there better ways?

Comment: Question unclear. What is the logic that gives the value for `:age`?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly shorter:

```
hsh.keys.zip(arr){|k, v| hsh[k] = v}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Ruby v1.9+ (hash keys had no ordering in earlier versions) and you know the order of the values in `arr` corresponds with the (insertion) order of the keys in the hash, then you can write:

(first way deleted because inferior to @sawa's answer)

If `arr` can be mutated (modified), you could do it like this:

```
hsh.each_key { |k| hsh[k] = arr.shift }
  #=> {:name=>"joe", :age=>"23", :height=>"179", :weight=>"70"}
```

or you could write:

```
e = arr.to_enum
hsh.each_key { |k| hsh[k] = e.next }
  #=> {:name=>"joe", :age=>"23", :height=>"179", :weight=>"70"}
```

which does not mutate `arr`. There are many other ways as well.

Comment: Your answer was better than mine if you used `to_h`.

Comment: Except  I created a new hash then overwrote the original one. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more shorter

```
hsh.keys.zip(arr).to_h
# => {:name=>"joe", :age=>"19", :height=>"179", :weight=>"70"}
```

If `to_h` is not supported,

```
Hash[hsh.keys.zip(arr)]
# => {:name=>"joe", :age=>"19", :height=>"179", :weight=>"70"}
```

Comment: OP wants to modify `hsh`. I originally had `hsh = <your answer>` (in addition to the two ways that remain in my answer, but then concluded it made no sense to create a new hash to overwrite the old one, rather than just changing it in place.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do using [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) :

```
arr  = ["joe", "19", "179", "70"]
hash = {name: "", age: "", height: "", weight: ""}
hash.each_with_index { |(k, _), ind| hash[k] = arr[ind] }
hash # => {:name=>"joe", :age=>"19", :height=>"179", :weight=>"70"}
```